# SQL server group by different columns and create new variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table such as

```
Date X1 X2 Y
2010 1  1  120
2010 1  2  130
2010 1  3  140
2010 2  1  150
2010 2  2  160
2010 2  3  170
2011 1  1  180
2011 1  2  190
2011 1  3  200
2011 2  1  210
2011 2  2  220
2011 2  3  230
```

and so on. I would like to calculate the sum of Y's while grouping for the two X variables *individually* and the Date variable. In the end I need two Y sums in two new columns with only 1 X variable (since the values of X1 and X2 represent the same concept). The output would look like

```
Date X Y1           Y2
2010 1 120+130+140  120+150
2010 2 150+160+170  130+160
2010 3 0            140+170
2011 1 180+190+200  180+210
```

and so on. Is there a way to do this efficiently (performance is key)? I know I could use a window function to get the sum for the two X's independently in two columns, but how can I then group the results (Date, X)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `UNION ALL` query to split the `Y` values between each X value and then sum them in an outer query:

```
SELECT [Date], X, SUM(Y1) AS Y1, SUM(Y2) AS Y2
FROM (
  SELECT [Date], X1 AS X, Y AS Y1, 0 AS Y2
  FROM data
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT [Date], X2 AS X, 0, Y
  FROM data
) d
GROUP BY [Date], X
ORDER BY [Date], X
```

Output:

```
Date    X   Y1      Y2
2010    1   390     270
2010    2   480     290
2010    3   0       310
2011    1   570     390
2011    2   660     410
2011    3   0       430
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87248d/3)

Answer (score 1):

That's two queries combined:

```
select
  coalesce(t1.date, t2.date) as date,
  coalesce(t1.x, t2.x) as x,
  coalesce(t1.total, 0) as y1,
  coalesce(t2.total, 0) as y2
from
(
  select date, x1 as x, sum (y) as total
  from mytable
  group by date, x1
) t1
full outer join
(
  select date, x2 as x, sum (y) as total
  from mytable
  group by date, x2
) t2 on t2.date = t1.date and t2.x = t1.x
order by date, x;
```

I suggest these indexes for the query:

```
create index idx1 on mytable (date, x1, y);
create index idx2 on mytable (date, x2, y);
```

These indexes provide the data pre-sorted, so grouping and joining should be fast.